# Scrolling plan file

Tags: documentation

How do I create a scrolling plan file?  I read about their existence here http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/P/plan-file.html, but it doesn't explain how to actually make them.

Answer (score 3):

There's a compiler called [`asp`](http://www.crypticide.com/alecm/asp/asp.txt) for creating such files available [here](http://www.crypticide.com/alecm/asp/).

The problem with these now is that terminals are just too darn fast. This technique was used with slooow serial or dial-up connections. The techniques relies on sending a really large file consisting of text, carriage returns and sometimes newlines.

You can enjoy these files today by introducing a timing loop. Perhaps the easiest way is to use [`pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv).

```
pv -q -L 1200 .plan
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple really - a file filled with subsequent frames of a single line animation separated with a carriage return (**not** line feed) so each line overwrites the line before.

E.g., (\r is carriage return)

```
......<\r.....<.\r....<..\r...<...\r..<....\r.<.....\r<......\r
```

would animate an arrow moving left through some dots.  Delays can be created by having either multiple carriage returns, or repeating the same frame many times.

Comment: I tried this like so: `echo -e "...<\r..<.\r.<..\r<..." > ~/.plan`, but the result was "Plan:
...<^M..<.^M.<..^M<...".  The man of my finger says it's from Linux NetKit .17.  I'm running centos 5.2

Comment: Looks like finger on Linux is filtering it and escaping the non-printable characters.